# Why does Google Maps get blocked when I shrink the window?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dojo

I have a [web page](http://development.danrumney.com/development/cta-voronoi.html) that uses Google Maps. I'm using Dojo and I've created a widget to encapsulate the map.

The problem is that, whenever I shrink the width of the browser, the map gets overlaid with a white region that only disappears when I expand the window a little bit. After doing some research, I *believe* that this is to do with Google trying to ensure that the copyright warning isn't being hidden.

If you look at the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) for v3, you'll see under the resize event:

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes
>   size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')

So, if you look in my [GMaps.js](http://development.danrumney.com/development/app/GMaps.js) file:

```
    postCreate: function() {
        this._map = new gmaps.Map(this.domNode, this.mapOptions);
        win.global.GM = gmaps;
        on(win.global, 'resize', lang.hitch(this,function(){
            console.log("Resizing");
            gmaps.event.trigger(this._map, 'resize');
            this._map.setZoom( this._map.getZoom() );
        }))
    },
```

So, I've hooked up to the window resize event and it is definitely firing, but it doesn't seem to be helping.

My question(s):

- Is my theory that this is due to Google trying to protect their copyright correct?
- If not, is there something else I could be doing to cause this problem?
- If so, what do I need to be doing to make sure that this white blocker doesn't appear?

I don't see this in Firefox. I see this in Chrome Version 24.0.1312.52 m. This is on Windows.

Comment: Which browser do you use, For me there are no problems within the linked page? Maybe you must clear your cache.

Comment: Chrome. It's not a caching problem, though.

Comment: Also no issues with chrome for me.

Comment: Curious. I'm on 'Version 24.0.1312.52 m' on Windows. What version are you running?

Comment: same version on winXP(also no issue on win7)